# Using RoboSpice and RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java, robospice

I would like to know what is the best practice when using RoboSpice and RxJava together.
The only thing I've found so far is the ["RoboSpice and RxJava" thread in the RoboSpice Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/robospice/DvFgKwqTDys). I wonder if there is a recommended approach when integrating these 2 libraries

Comment: Best way is wrap robospice executes with `Observable`. It might be more easly if robospice had synchronous api.

Comment: You might want to try https://github.com/anotherdev/robospice-fluent-request.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @user802421